# How do I reference connected (container) component's props inside mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not understanding how ownProps work in the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), please help me clarify the below:

1. > If ownProps is specified as a second argument, its value will be the
   >   props passed to your component

If I have 3 components - 1. todoList, todo, and connectedTodo (`=connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, ownProps)(todo)`, and todolist renders a lot of connectedTodos and passes props to them, does that mean, todo will have access to the props passed down from todolist? If I didn't specify ownProps, then todo WON'T have access to the props passed to connectedTodo?

2. > mapStateToProps will be additionally re-invoked whenever the component
   >   receives new props

Does this mean that whenever todoList passes down new props to connectedTodo, its mapStateToProps will be invoked in addition to whenever the state it's subscribed to changes?

If I want to do some logic inside `mapStateToProps` and want to reference the connectedTodo's props, can I just use `this.props`?

Example:

```
const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  data: state.otherSlice.name === this.props.name ? state.data: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Todo will have access to passed props even if you will not specify `ownProps` as parameter. `ownProps` are good to use in cases like described in your second question.
2. If you need to have data property filled only if it has same name with component current `name` prop, how about this small code modification:

   ```
   function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
     return { 
       ...ownProps, 
       data: state.otherSlice.name === ownProps.name ? state.data : null 
     }
   }
   ```

There are several more samples at the bottom of the documentation page provided by you.